# How can I turn off the screen of my laptop while using an eGPU?

Tags: graphics, hybrid-graphics, external-monitor

I use my latop with an external graphic card (eGPU) through an express card slot.

As soon as, the eGPU is activated, the screen of the laptop is fixed. The blue image of the xubuntu loading is displayed continuously.

I am afraid of burn in, so I would like to turn it off.

However, this screen (LVDS1) is not listed in `xrandr`.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4960 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-3 connected primary 2560x1440+1200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 878mm x 485mm
HDMI-3 connected 1200x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
DVI-0 connected 1200x1920+3760+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
```

Closing the lid of the laptop didn't help also.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Close the lid perhaps?

Comment: as I already mentioned in my question, this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution.

1. Switch to tty1 by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1
2. Login
3. Force the display to turn off, by calling `setterm -blank force`
4. Switch back to X by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F7

I will try to write an upstart script to automate this.

Much, much more simpler :

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```